# Simulink, Generate polynomial Input signal

Tags: signals, system, simulink

I'm trying to simulate a system using simulink, I would like to generate a third degree polynomial function as input signal, but I don't understand which block I should use.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The [Polynomial Evaluation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/polynomialevaluation.html) is made exactly for this purpose. Assuming your function does not change, connect the second input to a constant block which holds the coefficients.